# What is the meaning of Argh?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

What does it mean to use `argh` in response to a question like this:

> Do you want to play?
> (All said) Argh.

This is a part of 'peppa pig' animation when it is Danny dog's birthday. All Danny dog's friends have come to his house and dressed as pirates. Danny's father is also dressed as a pirate and tells the children "do you wanna play? Say argh". Then In response they all say "argh" or maybe "ar"

Based on the context it seems to have the meaning of "yes"  for me.

Comment: Source and context please!  Tell us the source of this quote.  Also give the context. Who is talking to whom? Who are "all"

Comment: **Argh** and **ah/oh** (in some contexts), often followed by **no**  are all used as expressions or disappointment/disagreement/irritation/rejection. In some European languages, the equivalent is a guttural **ag**.

Comment: This is in the dictionary: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/argh

Comment: @JamesK I added the context.

Comment: @RonaldSole But it seems to mean "yes" in the context. I've added the context to question.

Comment: @MohammadBarbast Yes, I see that from JavaLatte's answer. I confess that I didn't go to the source material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The children are dressed as pirates. There is a common misconception that pirates say "Arrr" meaning yes: the children were acting on this misconception by saying "Arrr" to mean yes.

Here is some [more information](https://www.childrensmuseum.org/blog/why-do-pirates-say-arrr) about it.